# Index on DataTable ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I have a data table with more than **38 million** rows. To improve the performance when accessing the table I want to create an index for a concrete column.

**QUESTIONS**

- How long does the query take to complete?
- Is creating the index to improve the performance a good solution?

Comment: What's a "concrete column"?  What does the query look like?  The current execution plan?  How many of the 38M rows is your query likely to return?  The answer to your question will depend heavily on the answers to these questions.

Comment: Show us the definition of the table. Show us the query you are running. Show us the execution plan for that query.

Comment: There is no silver bullet that increases a performance of any query. Read [concepts](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/toc.htm) to understand how oracle works.

Answer (score 0):

Question #1: Depends on your setup and hardware. Hard to say anything without more information. You could try with a smaller set of data to get a feeling for how long it could take.

Qeustion #2: Yes. But it depends on your queries if an index on a specific column helps or not.